# Evaluate the integral $ \int_{0}^{\infty} {\frac{\sin ^3 (x)}{x} }\:dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate the integral $ \int_{0}^{\infty} {\frac{\sin ^3 (x)}{x} }\:dx$

Comment: the result should be $$\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can linearise $\sin^3(x)$ :
$${\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\sin^3\left(x\right)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x=-\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-1}{\dfrac{1}{4}}}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\sin\left(3x\right)-3\sin\left(x\right)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x=-\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-1}{\dfrac{1}{4}}}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\sin\left(3x\right)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x+\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-1}{\dfrac{3}{4}}}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x$$$$=\dfrac{3\operatorname{Si}\left(x\right)}{4}-\dfrac{\operatorname{Si}\left(3x\right)}{4}+C$$
Finally :
$${\displaystyle\int}_0^\infty\dfrac{\sin^3\left(x\right)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{3\operatorname{Si}\left(\infty\right)}{4}-\dfrac{\operatorname{Si}\left(\infty\right)}{4}-\dfrac{3\operatorname{Si}\left(0\right)}{4}+\dfrac{\operatorname{Si}\left(0\right)}{4}\\=\dfrac{\operatorname{Si}\left(\infty\right)}{2}-\dfrac{\operatorname{Si}\left(0\right)}{2}$$
But $\operatorname{Si}\left(0\right)=0$ and $\operatorname{Si}\left(\infty\right)=\frac\pi2 :$
$${\displaystyle\int}_0^\infty\dfrac{\sin^3\left(x\right)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac\pi4$$

Answer (score 4):

We have
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(mx)}{x}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2} $$
for any $m\in\mathbb{N}^+$, hence it is enough to expand $\sin^3(x)$ as a Fourier sine series. Actually
$$ \sin^3(x) = \frac{3}{4}\sin(x)-\frac{1}{4}\sin(3x) $$
hence
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^3(x)}{x}\,dx = \left(\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{4}\right)\frac{\pi}{2} = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{4}}.$$

Comment: Can you add $dx$ in the first equation ?

Comment: What's the difference between $\mathbb {N^+}$ and $\mathbb N$?

Comment: @JaideepKhare $\mathbb{N}^{+} = \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$

Comment: @ZainPatel $\mathbb N$ already is the set without $0$ i.e. $$\{ 1,2,3....\}$$

Comment: @JaideepKhare that's your convention, not necessarily Jack's.

Comment: @JaideepKhare: exactly, in Russia and other countries $\mathbb{N}$ usually stands for $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$, but in Italy, France and USA $\mathbb{N}$ usually stands for $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and that is the convention I am adopting.

Comment: @JaideepKhare It depends on the author/region. Some folks include $0$ in $\mathbb{N}$, and some folks don't. There is no right or wrong here...

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I didn't know that, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

$$4\sin^3 x=3\sin x-\sin 3x$$
Your integral is
$$\frac34\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}x\,dx
-\frac14\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin 3x}x\,dx.
$$